# My double click event is not working, when I double click on the marker, it does not delete

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

My double click event is not working, when I double click on the marker, it does not delete. Please help :). Here is my code. :) I've tried to fix it already by editing some stuff but it seems not to be working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC5dtn-wkog5K5cFZ0hN1uyiWo2kB89Lk0&sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var markersArray = [];

function initialize() {
   var haightAshbury = new google.maps.LatLng(37.7699298, -122.4469157);
   var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: haightAshbury,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
   };
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
      addMarker(event.latLng);
   });

   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dblclick', function() {
      clearOverlays();
   });
}

function clearOverlays() { 
   if (markersArray) { 
      for (i in markersArray) { 
         markersArray[i].setMap(null); 
      } 
   } 
}

function addMarker(location) {
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
   });
   markersArray.push(marker);
}

function deleteMarker() { 
   map.setMap(null);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are both 'click' and 'dblclick' events firing? are you doubleclicking on the map or marker? if you doubleclick the marker, you need to add an event listener to the marker, NOT the map

Answer (score 0):

```
function addMarker(location) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', 
    // closure so the callback remembers the marker
    (function(what){
      return function() {
        what.setMap(null);
        // you might want to remove it from markersArray here too
      };
    )(marker)
  );
  });

  markersArray.push(marker);
}
```